# PHP Simple post to URL with fields and show the answer from server

Tags: php

I'm new to php and i want to send some data to a url and write the respond from server.
Whatever i try the response is empty
Here is the code

```
$post_data['userid'] = "demo";
$post_data['password'] = "demo";
$post_data['to'] = "$to";
$post_data['message'] = iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1253","$text");
$post_data['from'] = 'sender';

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = curl_init('http://www.lexiconsoftware.gr/sms/warrior.asp');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curld, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

//show information regarding the request
//print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
//echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' . curl_error($curl_connection);
$getresult = curl_get_contents($result);
echo $getresult;
$http_data = curl_exec($curld);
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($curld);
$headers = substr($http_data, 0, $curl_info['header_size']); //split out header
echo "Message Status: $http_data, headers: $headers<br><a href=\"smser.php\">Send New</a>"; 

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);
```

The code sends the data but there is no response, just an empty page

Comment: What happens when you insert the following lines at the top of your file? `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` ?

Comment: A bunch of errors but still the sms goes OK, i mean the post is OK, but with no response

Comment: Without `CURLOPT_POST` it is a `GET` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First of all you use `$curld` but it is not initialized by curl_init. Use `$curl_connection` instead.
2) I don't see any `curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, true);`
3) Do not use foreach and implode(). For a case your data may contain `&` use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)() with:
`curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));`
4) You set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `TRUE`. It is ok. So check your `$result`:
`echo $result = curl_exec($curl_connection);`
5) There is no `curl_get_contents` in the curl.

Comment: I thing i am using $curl_connection

Answer (score 0):

Firstly:

```
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
```

You are doing it wrong. passed data should be urlencoded. You can just pass `$post_data` to `curl_setopt` with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and it will create request body for you.

Now

```
$getresult = curl_get_contents($result);
```

What is `curl_get_contents`? you are using `curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` so `$result` will be your response body.

And now, why there is second curl connection `$curld` and how does it relate to your question? There is no code that initiates this connection.

Comment: I told you i'm new and i come from asp.net. This code is from 3-4 sources and is not very cear for me all the commands. But it's working. The purpose is to send SMS and it does, but with no response.
I know $result is the response body but why its empty or not printed?

Comment: In your code there is no attempt to print `$result`, that's why I'm asking what is `curl_get_contents`, since it is not native php function. Also, running code from various sources without understanding it, only invites disaster. Please at least get familiar with functions used in the code, to be sure it will not do any harm.